# Exchanging probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

I have that $P(a < X_n | F_n) >p$, if I want to find $P(a > X_n | F_n)$, can I just reverse the (direction) probability and does $P(a>X_n | F_n) < 1-p$ or $P(a>X_n | F_n) > 1-p$? Note, $F_n$ is a filtration.

Also, if $P(a < X_n | F_n) >p$, can I say that $P(a < X_{cn} | F_{cn}) >p$ for a constant $c$?

Answer (score 1):

First part:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(a>X_n|\mathcal{F}_n)&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}(a>X_n)|\mathcal{F}_n)\\
&=1-\mathbb{E}(1-\mathbb{1}(a>X_n)|\mathcal{F}_n)\\
&=1-\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}(a\leq X_n)|\mathcal{F}_n)\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(a\leq X_n|\mathcal{F}_n)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas for the 2nd part?

Comment: @Murer Yes. Perhaps you could edit your question to include your attempt at the second part?